# Is there a way to get DOM-element's actual HTML even if malformed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If HTML-code is malformed, the browser will sometimes adjust the HTML when rendering the page.

Example - some code inserted in `<table>` outside of `td` - this is against the rules and obviously malformed... So the browser (any browser) adjusts the HTML-code. Check the example. The `array` bit will be moved outside the table.

```js
document.getElementById("txt").value = document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <table>
  
    {{#array}}
    <tr><td>blah blah</td></tr>
    {{/array}}

  </table>
</div>


<textarea id="txt" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Is there any way to get the ACTUAL, ORIGINAL INNER HTML even if it's malformed? I tried googling but found nothing.

Comment: How does it get there in the first place?

Comment: You cannot get it from the DOM (as that would be broken in that case). You can, though, fire a fetch on the resource in question and get what you're looking for from the String you're getting.

Comment: Browsers parse the input HTML to create a DOM, they are traditionally very tolerant of malformed markup, but different parsers may correct it differently. Any subsequent DOM methods, such as innerHTML, will be based on that DOM, not the original source.

Comment: @baklazan frontend templating markup. Like angular, Mustache etc etc

Comment: @RobG I know WHY it happens, I asked is there any workaround. Guess not

Comment: Comments and answers are for everyone who might visit in the future, not just the OP. The duplicate is your answer (thought it lacks actual code). :-/